# Azure AAD authentication, clicked on wrong microsoft ID in browser and now authentication fails every time

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-explorer

I was running a python program to fetch data from Azure Data Explorer, process it and write. The way I authenticate is:

```
import os
os.system("az login")
#browser pops up, I click on the relevant microsoft account and login.
```

I can now go back to my IDE and continue with my program. After finishing coding my programs, I restarted the kernel and ran it again for testing. This time, on the browser, I accidently clicked on the wrong micrsoft azure account and the login succeeded (because it was a valid login), but I knew it was wrong so I immediately restarted my kernel again. But ever since then I've been stuck at an error when I actually run a query:

```
'Caller is not authorized to perform this action', '@type': 'Kusto.DataNode.Exceptions.UnauthorizedDatabaseAccessException',
```

I tried cleaning the cache with `az`

```
az cache purge
#no output on console
```

I tried going to a different browser, closing everything and restarting. I also tried to find `kusto` or `azure-data-explorer` folders under `AppData` in the windows system and manually deleting the cache, but didn't find any such folders. Note: I haven't restarted the system yet, it's an ec2 instance and I have a lot of work open.

I am able to run the same program normally on a different windows machine succesfully. How can I fix this in an easy way in the future? I normally don't use windows or Azure for development work.

Comment: Can you please check if the wrong selected account is connected in IE(Or the default browser) and try to disconnect from it and reopen your program.

Comment: @Houssem I tried that, It didn't work. I have now also restarted my system, still not working.

Comment: then , can you execute `az logout` it should work.

Comment: It didn't work, but I liked the idea so I went to `az logout` docs, then individually signed out from all accounts by  name. Then it worked. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_logout

Comment: @Houssem do you mind posting an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `az logout`command should do the work and let you logout from the current active accounts.

But as your tests this don't work for you so a second alternative is to use az logout with all specific accounts `az logout --username` -[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_logout)